# Compute clustered correct standard errors from lm.fit() object while also correcting DoF

Tags: r, lm

I am running a linear regression with many levels of fixed effects and which takes a long time to run.

Due to efficiency reasons, I would like to:

1. demean the variables once (for this I am using `demeanlist()` from the `lfe` package.
2. save the demean matrix
3. run `lm.fit()` on the demeaned matrix instead of `lm()` for efficiency reasons (the dataset has more than 50 Million rows)
4. save the output from `lm.fit()`
5. apply to the output the SE correction to account for

   1. clustering/heteroskedasticity (ideally here I would like to try different things without having to rerun the model every time)
   2. the true number of DoF which is lower than the default one in `lm.fit()` since `lm.fit()` does not take into account the demeaning part.
6. output to Latex with stargazer

I have tried 1-4 successfully and now I am wondering how to tackle 5. Ideally also 6 but of course it is minor.

I am open of course to alternatives to 4. I do not have to strictly run `lm.fit()`, I am ok with anything from `fastLm()`, `felm()`

EDIT: Minimal self-contained example

```
library(fastDummies)
library(felm)    
library(lfe)    

data <- data.frame(author=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
                   date=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), sub=c("political", "general", "political", "general","political", "general", "political", "general","political", "general", "political", "general"), treatment1=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1), outcome=c(0,2,5,5,7,0,1,1,23,3,10,11), treatment2= c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))


yX <- data[,c("treatment1", "treatment2", "outcome")]


cx <- demeanlist(yX, list(as.factor(data$author), as.factor(data$sub), as.factor(data$date)))


x <- lm.fit(as.matrix(cx[,1:2]), as.matrix(cx[3]))
```

I want now to have a summary of x which I can output to Latex but in which I may correct the DoFs and I can cluster SE or use heteroskedasticity-robust SEs.

Comment: You might be interested in `lmtest::coeftest` which calculates clustered standard errors from model fits. Would you mind to design a [self-contained minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) to show us what you're doing?

Comment: Why the Rcpp tag?

Comment: Agree with @Ralf and suggest you remove the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: @RalfStubner you are right sorry. I thought to do ask the question more specifically targeted to fastLm() from RcppEigen package and to ask specifically also if there are some Rcpp commands to compute fastly SE corrections (which I assume would gain a lot from Rcpp). In the end I went for a more general question and forgot to remove the tag! Sorry and thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @jay.sf Hi jay, example added! Thanks a lot!